# Create a copy of each version of a file in a git repository

Tags: git, bash, command-line

I want to copy each committed version of `InterestingFile.cpp` to a directory.

The destination file should have its commit timestamp as filename (like `/tmp/AllVersions/1495035445`)

The following example works, but requires a `helper.sh` script. How can I write in one line without helper script?

```
$ git rebase -i --exec "~/helper.sh ~/InterestingFile.cpp" --preserve-merges 0123ABCD


$ cat ~/helper.sh  
#!/bin/bash
TIMESTAMP=`git show -s --format=%ct HEAD` 
cp $1 /tmp/AllVersions/${TIMESTAMP}


$ ls -1 /tmp/AllVersions  # here are the files finally
1499951860
1500038126
1500040256
1500363092
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rebase -i --exec "cp ~/InterestingFile.cpp /tmp/AllVersions/$(git show -s --format=%ct HEAD)" --preserve-merges 0123ABCD
```